# Can I use a returned action payload in a subsequent dispatch in redux?

Tags: redux

Wondering if it is good practice to use the data returned from an action creator in a subsequent call to dispatch? Example:

```
let payload = addItem('new item');
dispatch(payload);

// Do subsequent action with data from previous action
dispatch(doSomethingElse(payload.item.id));
```

Comment: Can you provide some more details to the question? I assume you are asking if you can apply multiple dispatch but it is very much unclear from the statement.